# Missing link between Java javax.smartcardio and OpenPGP functionality

Tags: java, smartcard, yubikey

As I understand, Yubikey NEO in CCID mode can be used as a SmartCard. I connected it, configured using GnuPG and tested using Kleopatra: encrypted a text file.

Is it possible to encrypt data with Yubikey NEO (as GnuPG does) using pure Java? The existence of javax.smartcardio API suggests that it is possible.

The closest thing I found is [OpenSC-Java project](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC-Java) but I can't find a data encryption example.